# How to properly transfer control between two sets of threads back and forth

Tags: c++, multithreading

I would like to implement a thread pool with C++ 11’s standard library only. The interface I would like to expose is to allow my main thread to commit many jobs at once, and wait until all threads to be finished to move on. It is my first time to deal with threads explicitly, so inevitably I run into some deadlock issue. Here is my code:

```cpp
class CrashQueue {
private:
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;
    std::queue<void*> payloads;
    std::function<void(void*)> function;
    std::mutex taskFetchingMutex;
    long aliveWorkers;

    std::condition_variable alarmClock;
    std::condition_variable sleepClock;
    std::mutex sleepClockMutex;
    bool running = true;

public:
    CrashQueue(std::size_t threadCount = std::thread::hardware_concurrency()) {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < threadCount; i ++) {
            workers.emplace_back([this]() -> void {
                while (running) {
                    void* payload;
                    {
                        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(taskFetchingMutex);
                        if (payloads.empty()) {
                            aliveWorkers --;
                            if (aliveWorkers == 0)
                                sleepClock.notify_one();
                            alarmClock.wait(lock);
                            continue;
                        }
                        payload = payloads.front();
                        payloads.pop();
                    }

                    function(payload);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    ~CrashQueue() {
        running = false;
        alarmClock.notify_all();
        for (auto& worker : workers)
            worker.join();
    }

    void run() {
        this->aliveWorkers = workers.size();
        alarmClock.notify_all();

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(sleepClockMutex);
        sleepClock.wait(lock);
    }

    void commit(std::function<void(void*)>&& function, std::queue<void*>&& payloads) {
        this->function = std::move(function);
        this->payloads = std::move(payloads);
    }
};
```

I suspect the issue is in the constructor’s lambda expression executed in worker threads:

```cpp
if (payloads.empty()) {
    aliveWorkers --;
    if (aliveWorkers == 0)
        sleepClock.notify_one();
    alarmClock.wait(lock);
    continue;
}
```

It might be the case that the last worker wake up the main thread and sleeps *after* the main thread wakes up all other threads. Nonetheless, it seems very unlikely, but the deadlock happens every time I am not in debug mode. Any hint?

Comment: `aliveWorkers` must be `std::atomic<long>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem somehow relates to the fact that I am using two mutexes here. Rewriting `run` as follows makes it work:

```
void run() {
    this->aliveWorkers = workers.size();
    alarmClock.notify_all();

    while (true) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(taskFetchingMutex);
        if (aliveWorkers.load() == 0)
            break;
        sleepClock.wait(lock);
    }
}
```

However, I could not visualize the picture to see why the original code could fail. Any answer explaining that is still wanted.

Edit: A complete source of my seemingly correct code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>
#include <queue>

class CrashQueue {
private:
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;
    std::queue<void*> payloads;
    std::function<void(void*)> function;
    std::mutex taskFetchingMutex;
    std::atomic<long> aliveWorkers;

    std::condition_variable alarmClock;
    std::condition_variable sleepClock;

    bool running = true;

public:
    CrashQueue(std::size_t threadCount = std::thread::hardware_concurrency())
    : aliveWorkers(threadCount) {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < threadCount; i ++) {
            workers.emplace_back([this]() -> void {
                while (running) {
                    void* payload;
                    {
                        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(taskFetchingMutex);
                        if (payloads.empty()) {
                            aliveWorkers.fetch_sub(1);
                            sleepClock.notify_one();

                            alarmClock.wait(lock);
                            continue;
                        }
                        payload = payloads.front();
                        payloads.pop();
                    }

                    function(payload);
                }
            });
        }

        // Make sure all workers finished running.
        while (aliveWorkers.load() > 0);
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(taskFetchingMutex);
    }

    ~CrashQueue() {
        running = false;
        alarmClock.notify_all();
        for (auto& worker : workers)
            worker.join();
    }

    void run() {
        this->aliveWorkers = workers.size();
        alarmClock.notify_all();

        while (true) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(taskFetchingMutex);
            if (aliveWorkers.load() == 0)
                break;
            sleepClock.wait(lock);
        }
    }

    void commit(std::function<void(void*)>&& function, std::queue<void*>&& payloads) {
        this->function = std::move(function);
        this->payloads = std::move(payloads);
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you made `aliveWorkers` atomic? I notice you've used `aliveWorkers.load()` but in the question it's just `long`. That's not the complete answer with a `condition_variable`.
You should make `running` atomic and initialize `aliveWorkers` to 0.
You also aren't sychronizing `function` and `payloads` in `commit()`.  Note that threads might start processing before you call run if `commit()` is called before all the threads have reached `if(payloads.empty())` for the first time. As a key point I suspect you don't yet fully understand memory barriers.

Comment: @Persixty Exactly, I have not yet systematically looked at any materials on concurrency, and my initial motivation for using atomic variables is to avoid locks. As I said, due to my lack of knowledge I thought that would be an easy task. I indeed change `aliveWorkers` and just pasted the complete source code on gist, with link updated in the answer.

Comment: @Persixty I would agree with your point on synchronizing `function` and `payloads`, but how should I solve that? I believe that locking some `mutex` would not help.

Comment: @Persixty One way that should work is to call `run` in the constructor. It seems guaranteed (or at least I would the guarantee in place) that after `run` all my workers are idle, after which any commit would be safe.

Comment: I would just wait until `aliveWorkers` go down to zero.

Comment: Ans1: You need to mofify aliveWorkers under the `mutex` even if it is atomic. It's not just about memory synchronization but ensuring that lock/unlock+wait/wakeup/relock are ordered with data modifications. See note here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable "Even if the shared variable is atomic, it must be modified under the mutex in order to correctly publish the modification to the waiting thread."

NB: Notify can (probably should) take place outside the mutex.

Comment: Ans 2: Synchronizing on the mutex will absolutely help `function` and `payloads`. Notice `function` is read outside the lock so you need to be sure it synchronized and won't by modified later. That or take a local copy when holding the mutex.

Comment: Ans 3: But you risk aliveWorkers being small because uninitialized and miss-notifying completion. Also your wait at the end of `run()` risks "spurious wakeup" which means it needs a predicate and you need to run it under the `aliveWorkers` mutex.